# Why is [String] the inferred type when there are no lists visible in the code?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I have this test:

```
testReadFile = runTestTT $ TestLabel "InteractionDomain.readFileContentsToList" (TestList [
    (TestLabel "testing infrastructure: read test file" (TestList [
        TestCase (withTempFileContainingText (\fileHandle ->
            assertEqual "contents as expected" "The dog barks at midnight." (do 
                content <- hGetContents fileHandle
                return content)))]))])
```

and (in case it helps) `withTempFileContainingText` is this function

```
withTempFileContainingText lambda = 
        bracketOnError 
            (do (path, fileHandle) <- openTempFile "." "input.txt"
                return fileHandle)
            (deleteFile)
            (\fileHandle -> do 
                hPutStr fileHandle "The dog barks at midnight."
                hClose fileHandle --hoping this flushes buffers
                return (lambda fileHandle))
```

`ghc` complains that

```
InteractionDomain.hs:36:4:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO String'
           against inferred type `[String]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: content ≤- hGetContents fileHandle
```

Which I don't understand. Why is there the inference that `content` is a list of String? And what should this code look like?

Comment: Lisp programmer, by any chance? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for some valuable pointers.

This runs and passes:

```
withTempFileContainingText lambda = 
        bracketOnError 
            (openTempFile "." "input.txt")
            (\(filePath, fileHandle) -> do
                removeFile filePath)
            (\(filePath, fileHandle) -> do
                startOfFile <- hGetPosn fileHandle 
                hPutStr fileHandle "The dog barks at midnight."
                hFlush fileHandle
                hSetPosn startOfFile
                lambda fileHandle
                removeFile filePath)


testReadFile = runTestTT $ TestLabel "InteractionDomain.readFileContentsToList" (TestList [
    (TestLabel "testing infrastructure: read test file" (TestList [
        TestCase (withTempFileContainingText (\fileHandle -> do
            content <- hGetContents fileHandle 
            assertEqual "contents as expected" "The dog barks at midnight." content))]))])
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, what I see right away is a type mismatch in your assertion.

assertEqual is `String -> a -> a -> Assertion`. You pass a `String` as the second argument, meaning a `String` should also be the third argument. However, your `do` expression is not returning `String`, but rather `IO String`.

Edit: To expand, once you mess with `IO`, you can't ever ditch it. You correctly extract the value out of IO with your `<-`, but then immediately wrap it back into `IO` with `return`. If you want to use the string, you must do it inside `IO`, something like:

```
do
  contents <- hGetContents handle
  assertEqual "They're equal" "Expected string" contents
```

Note that then your `do` would be returning `IO Assertion`. If you want to use the assertion value, you'd need to unwrap it similarly, and so on. Haskell doesn't let you get away with (hidden) side effects!

Comment: Kenny is right about Assertion just being an IO (). I actually haven't used HUnit before :) I'll edit the return out of my example.

Comment: Yes, you can ditch it. Its called `unsafePerformIO`. (Not that you _should_) ;)

Answer (score 3):

The type of `assertEqual` is

```
assertEqual :: String -> a -> a -> Assertion
```

Since the 2nd argument “`"The dog barks at midnight."`” is a String, we know `a` must be `String`. Therefore the do expression

```
do 
  content <- hGetContents fileHandle
  return content
```

must return a String. But String = [Char], therefore Haskell will regard this as a List monad. I don't know why it infers a [String] instead of a [Char] = String, but this at least explains where the List comes.

---

BTW, an Assertion is already an IO (). If you `return` an assertion you'll get an IO (IO ()). Probably you mean

```
withTempFileContainingText :: (Handle -> IO c) -> IO c
withTempFileContainingText lambda = 
    bracketOnError 
        (return . snd =<< openTempFile "." "input.txt")
        (deleteFile)
        (\fileHandle -> do
            hPutStr fileHandle "The dog barks at midnight."
            hClose fileHandle
            lambda fileHandle)   -- # <--- No return here
```

then the `testCase` can be written as

```
testCase :: Assertion
testCase = withTempFileContainingText $ \fileHandle -> do
    conts <- hGetContents fileHandle
    assertEqual "contents as expected" "The dog barks at midnight." conts
    -- # ^-- No return here.
```

Comment: It's a shame that ghc reports the wrong problem in the wrong place.